# using general class for Selenium automation test with java

Tags: java, selenium

I am really new to automation test with Selenium and Java, I want to create a General class to store methods that will use in others class, like Login, Click a button... 
In other class, I will do test that open page, input username, password and click on some element. 
my code as below: 
GeneralMethods:

```
public class GeneralMethods {

String baseURL;
String chromepath =".../Webdriver/chromedriverv2.36";

public WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void openBrowser() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromepath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseURL);

}
public void loginAccount(String username, String password) {

}
public void clickOnElement() {
    //TODO: click on web element which other class will call 
}
public void closeBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
}
public void refreshBrowser() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.F5);
}
```

The class login and click on some element here:

```
public class LoginUser extends GeneralMethods {

String baseURL = "mydomain";
String username = "myusername123@gmail.com";
String userpassword = "mypassword123";

@BeforeTest
public void openBrowser() {
    driver.get(baseURL);
}
@Test
public void loginEmployer() {
    //TODO: Login an user with username and password 
}

@Test 
public void clickOnButton() {
    //TODO: click on a button with Xpath 
}
```

}

please help me correct the code an suggest me how to research if there any problem.

Comment: You should read up on page object model. It's a best practice for test automation. I would suggest just reading more Selenium documentation in general. Your `refreshBrowser()` method is provided by Selenium, e.g. `driver.navigate().refresh();` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion** :

1. Your all utilities like loginAccount , ClickOnElement , refreshBrowser , everything should be in GeneralMethods class.
2. You may extends your Test class from GeneralMethods class. (Like you've already done.)
3. Your Utility class does not need to contain any TestNG annotations.
4. **Test Method**  @Test 
   public void clickOnButton() { }

In your LoginUser can't be test method , as clicking on a button is just interaction with WebElement.

5. For your code : public void **refreshBrowser**() {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.F5);
   }

use this code : **driver.navigate().refresh();**

6. **String baseURL** instance field in your GeneralMethods class is not initialized, you may face runtime Exception while running the code.

Comment: I have a structure code and written really simple, but it not work at all